# How do I fix error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https

I already have an SSL certificate active but want to force the use of https, and have sought I've tried several rules but always yields the same error.

My rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]

RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Irbx.jpg)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnyJq.jpg)

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I always get an error that says the page has redirection loops .

Comment: Your code is ok. Do you have any other rules?

Comment: yes, I try with different rules, always throws the same error

Comment: Please post them in your question.

Comment: ahh, my .htaccess only has those lines , try with different rules but always get the same error .

Comment: Try clearing your browser's cache.

Comment: Yes, try clearing your cache. Also, have a look at [this](https://github.com/phanan/htaccess#force-https).

Comment: and I try, to probe with other browsers and does not work

Comment: Open up your console (F12) and reload the page. Post a screenshot of the Network tab.

Comment: Thanks for your help , in the end you can not do with htaccess , create redirects from my cpanel server and it worked .

Comment: I wanted to see the content of the network tab, not the console. You can do it with `.htaccess`, but something may be interfering, which is why I want to see the content of the network tab.

Comment: You can see for yourself 
www.ingmega.com/syspagos/

Answer (score 0):

The redirect works for me. Make sure you don't have any cached result.

```
➜  ~  curl -i www.ingmega.com/syspagos
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 02 Feb 2016 19:22:12 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: https://syspagos.ingmega.com
Content-Length: 236
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://syspagos.ingmega.com">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>

➜  ~  curl -i https://syspagos.ingmega.com
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

However, please note that your site is returning a self-signed certificate. The certificate you provided is untrusted.

Comment: delete the cache , try another browser from another PC , from mobile , and always throws the same error, the certificate does not present problems , deleting rules htaccses and direct access with https in the url shows me secure connection

Comment: Try from a different machine and compare the result of the `curl`. What is the result of `curl` from your machines?